# Floor is lava, need answer

Tags: science-based, natural-disasters, cities, lava

Imagine a tsunami of lava has flash-flooded cities. Oddly enough there weren't eruptions or earthquakes, just a sea of molten rock covering every inch of road, street pavement, what have you. According to a volcano expert, the lava will take at least a year to cool and settle down... BTW every experts is being dispatched to the field but have yet to come out with a good explanation about where all the lava came from, and how the lava is able to cover nearly 50% of the land surfaces on Earth. What could have cause this phenomenon?

Comment: "I *told* you that fish was magic, and that your stupid wish would come true and hurt a lot of people."

Comment: The math is beyond me, but I think that cranking up the nuclear decay inside of the Earth to make the entire crust liquid should be a good explanation. By the way if the floor is lava everywhere and the entire curst has molten you'll have at most 2 hours to live. That is if you are sitting in Central Asia. The evaporating oceans steam explosions will kill everything there last. After that you've turned Earth into a watery version of Venus. I wonder if there is an xkdc about this...

Comment: "_According to a volcano expert, the lava will take at least a year to cool and settle down_" haha, no. If there was enough lava that it would take a year to cool down, there would be no living volcano experts any more.

Comment: Note that unless [Convection Schmonvection](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ConvectionSchmonvection) is in play, having all the roads and streets be covered in lava means that everything else is going to be on fire, melting and sinking into the lava, or both. (**WARNING**: TVTropes link)

Comment: Plus lava is so dense it's going to knock down most things in its path other than landforms and solid concrete blocks.

Answer (score 2):

There's more than enough magma down there to do this, something geological/magical which caused large vents or pores to open up and spew it out very evenly would do this. Increasing the pressure in the mantle would require unthinkable amounts of energy but might give the right sort of effect.

A question though: flooding only affects low lying areas. If anywhere higher is affected, the lower cities will be under hundreds of feet of lava, not just a thin layer. My house is on a hill, does this mean I am fine, or are you looking for magical lava which will be the same thickness all the way up a slope?

Second question: what about the oceans which cover most of the planet, and which are, be definition, low lying -- will all the water boil off, or will lava flow be (magically?) restricted to areas above sea level.